# Error in length of variable given to aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the code where I'm making a ggplot about a call center's calls. I'm trying to forecast the data so that it will show all the calls within 15 minutes of the business. This is my ggplot:

```
ggplot(data = micelSeason, aes(x = micelby15, y = counts)) +
  # plot the raw data
  geom_line() +
  # add the forecast
  geom_line(data = augment(forecast_1, newdata = mi_training), 
            aes(x = micelby15, y = .fitted),
            color = "red") +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Calls") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "15 Min", date_labels = "%H-%M")
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): x
Backtrace:
 1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. ggplot2 (local) by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 6. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 7. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 8. ggplot2 (local) f(..., self = self)
 9. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)
 Error in check_aesthetics(evaled, n) :
```

If anyone has any tips or solutions for this problem at all that would be a huge help.

I tried checking my variables to see thus they make sense, and I'm pretty sure I followed the guide pretty well. I used this website to help me: **https://nicholasrjenkins.science/post/tidy_time_series/tts_r/**

It says it's an aesthetics issue, so I figured it has to do with the coloring, but I tried deleting my only color feature and adding some but I couldn't get it to work.

The data I was using only had one column, and it was the time that there was a call received at the call center. So it was a column of DateTime values ranging from 13:00 to 17:00 on October 3rd, 2022. Below are the packages I was using and some of my other codes:

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(fpp2)
library(TTR)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
library(rsample)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

micelFifteen <- data.frame(micel[['STARTTIME']])
micelFifteen$by15 <- cut(micelFifteen$micel...STARTTIME..., breaks = "15 min")
micelFifteen['counts']  <-  1
micelFifteen.summary <- aggregate(counts ~ by15, FUN =sum, data=micelFifteen)
micelFifteen.summary


micelFifteen.summary['time_trend'] <- 1:nrow(micelFifteen.summary) 
micelSeason <- micelFifteen.summary %>% 
  mutate(seasonal_trend = hour(micelFifteen.summary$by15))
glimpse(micelSeason)


micelsplit <- initial_time_split(micelSeason, prop = 2/3)
mi_training <- training(micelsplit)
mi_testing <- testing(micelsplit)

forecast_1 <- lm(counts ~ time_trend , data = mi_training)
broom::tidy(forecast_1)

augment(forecast_1, newdata = mi_training)

michaelby15<- as.POSIXct(michaelFifteen.summary$by15)


ggplot(data = micelSeason, aes(x = micelby15, y = counts)) +geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = augment(forecast_1, newdata = mi_training),aes(x = micelby15, y = .fitted), color = "red") + labs(x = "Time", y = "Calls") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "15 Min", date_labels = "%h-%m")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  The problem is with (what you are doing to) your data.  You haven't given us your data.  Nor have you indicated which packages you are using.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: @Limey Hi, thank you for letting me know! I just added my code, packages, and more info on my data!

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(micelSeason))`.

Comment: Is the issue with the `micelSeason` `geom_line` or with the other? (If you don't know, you can comment out the lines that pertain to each and see if it runs.) Presumably it's just one that causes the problem and you can leave the other out of your question to help get to an answer quicker.

Comment: Does this simpler example work for you? `library(ggplot); ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + geom_line(data = broom::augment(forecast_1, newdata = mtcars), aes(x = wt, y = .fitted))`

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg